# What's the reccommended way to provide types in an Angular shared module?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules

I have a `SharedModule` where I have a `PhoneInputComponent` that you can bind a custom interface to it:

```
export interface PhoneNumber {
  prefix: string;
  value: string;
}
```

I currently have a `models/` folder inside my `SharedModule` directory and there I've placed the `phone-number.model.ts`.

What's the official pattern on where to place these UI-model files? Please add links to official resources

Comment: I don't know any official pattern. You can create your own patters. I put all my custom interfaces in the folder src/interfaces, but this is really up to you.

Comment: We separate ours by use. Tightly coupled and loosely coupled. Tightly coupled models are interfaces that you would only ever use in conjunction with a specific component / scenario. These are defined in the angular module in which the relevant component resides. Loosely coupled models are cross-cutting, such as domain models. These reside in a ES6 module which can be imported anywhere as needed. This second category was introduced when we began using Angular Libraries. If you have everything in the same codebase/project, the former approach is likely sufficient to avoid needless overhead.